# Mixed partials on the diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, hyperbolic-equations

Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $\varphi\in C^2(I^2;\mathbb{R})$ be twice continuously-differentiable on $I^2:=I\times I$.

We call $\varphi$ *separable* if it can be written $\varphi\equiv\varphi(x,y) = \alpha(x) + \beta(y)$ for some $\alpha,\beta: I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and we call $\varphi$ *non-separable* if for each open $\mathcal{O}\subseteq I^2$ the restriction $\varphi_{\mathcal{O}}:=\left.\varphi\right|_{\mathcal{O}}$ is not separable.

**Remark:** For any $U\subseteq I^2$ open and connected, the function $\varphi_U$ is separable iff $\left.(\partial_x\partial_y\varphi)\right|_U = 0$; consequently $\varphi$ is non-separable if and only if the set $\{z\in I^2\,|\,\partial_x\partial_y\varphi(z)\neq 0\}$ is dense in $I^2$.

**Question:** Is it true that: If $\varphi$ is non-separable, then $\{x\in I \,|\,\partial_x\partial_y\varphi(x,x)\neq 0\}$ is dense in $I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

**Example:** Take $I=(0,1)$, and
$$
\varphi(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x=y\\
\exp(-1/(x-y)^2) & x<y\\
\exp(-2/(x-y)^2) & x>y.
\end{cases}
$$
By construction, $\varphi$ is smooth with derivatives of all order vanishing on the diagonal.  But $\varphi$ isn't separable.  Indeed, the mixed partial does not vanish anywhere else.

Comment: Indeed, thank you! @user10354138